# mySQL union allow for non match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that will pull some product information AND photos, if the product has any.

```
select
    prod.pID, prod.Manufacturer_Name, prod.pUPC, prod.pNum, prod.pPrice, prod.pSalesPrice, prod.pSalesDate, prod.pSalesEndDate, prod.pSale,
    GROUP_CONCAT(photoName) as photos
from
    ds_products as prod
    inner join ds_photos as pics on pics.objectID=prod.pID
where
   pics.photoFlag =2
group by 
   prod.pID
```

The problem with this is that products that do not have photos get left out of the result set.  What do I need to add and/or change to allow for a product that doesn't appear in the photos table to show up in the results?

Thanks

*EDIT*

I tried the LEFT JOIN instead of inner but get the same result set.  If i run just:

```
select
    prod.pID, prod.Manufacturer_Name, prod.pUPC, prod.pNum, prod.pPrice, prod.pSalesPrice, prod.pSalesDate, prod.pSalesEndDate, prod.pSale
from
    ds_products as prod
```

I get about 600k results.  The inner and or left join queries get about 190k results.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outer join

```
select
    prod.pID, prod.Manufacturer_Name, prod.pUPC, prod.pNum, prod.pPrice, prod.pSalesPrice, prod.pSalesDate, prod.pSalesEndDate, prod.pSale,
    GROUP_CONCAT(photoName) as photos
from
    ds_products as prod
    LEFT join ds_photos as pics on pics.objectID=prod.pID
where
   pics.photoFlag =2 OR pics.photoFlag is NULL
group by 
   prod.pID
```

I have added a condition which check if photoFlag is null for the products which don't have corresponding pics
Here is working fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2a9c/1/0

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN like this

```
select
    prod.pID, prod.Manufacturer_Name, prod.pUPC, prod.pNum, prod.pPrice, prod.pSalesPrice, prod.pSalesDate, prod.pSalesEndDate, prod.pSale,
    GROUP_CONCAT(photoName) as photos
from
    ds_products as prod
    LEFT JOIN ds_photos as pics on pics.objectID=prod.pID
group by 
   prod.pID
```

Note I have also removed your where clause, as this was looking for a value in pics table that would restrict the result set.

Comment: I see a possible issue in that you are also limiting the records by pics.photoFlag = 2).  If there is not a record in pics, this will basically defeat the purpose of the left join, so you probably want to remove this. I have edited my answer.

Comment: The reason for the photoFlag option is because the db stores a link to multiple versions of each product image (thumb, full, etc) and photoFlag = 2 represents the full image. I don't want to need to test the image sizes of the result set to know which to use.  Or, is there a way to tag each photo url with it's photoFlag value? like 2*url_for_flag=2,4*url_for_flag=4,etc

Comment: @baiano The reason for the photoFlag is not really all that important to the query.  The bottom line is that if you want the query to return all products, whether they have a related image or not, you can't then filter on one of the image properties. Doing so will automatically remove all products without images from the result set.